# Get last battery charge date time from BatterManager

Tags: android

How do I get the last charge date/time from Android BatteryManager?
Well maybe it's not BatteryManager but some other API to use for this.

I want to display something like "Charged 2 hours ago".

Comment: Browsing through the class code you may use ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED Intent and log the appearance time of different BATTERY_STATUS* constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a broadcast reciever for [`ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED) intent and then you could store the time at which power was disconnected.

Comment: Do you know if the disconnected event is receivable when the app is not running at all?

Comment: if you register a broadcast receiver in manifest file, the app need not be running. The reciever will get registered on installing and continue to recieve events till the package is uninstalled. It does not matter if your app is running or not